# Access to a class object not assigned to anything

Tags: python, python-3.x

here is a super simple code:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.something = x
```

You can now make instance of class:

```
test1 = Test(14)
```

then access it:

```
test1.something
```

I am wondering if you not "assign" it to nothing like that:

```
Test(15)
```

Would it be just existing in memory without access to it or it goes somewhere to garbage or what?

```
print (Test(15))
<__main__.Test object at 0xb70aba8c>
```

Maybe little bit silly, I don't know. I am just curious, because it's clearly take some space in the memory. Thanks.

Comment: It will be immediately deleted after that line as the `ref_count` for that object will be zero... You don't need a class for that, the same will happen with a list for example

Comment: Just run this `print (Test(15))` twice in a row and see what is printed. This will give you an idea of what happens

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a REPL ("Read, Evaluate, Print, Loop", also known as a "Python/Language Shell"), it will actually be saved into the special name `_` which holds the result of the previously executed expression. As long as that name holds a reference to it, it will remain in memory.

If you're not in a REPL though, it will remain in memory only briefly. Since nothing is referencing the object, the reference count of the object will be 0, and memory associated with it will be freed.

Comment: Wow, nice one. Thank you.

Comment: REPL stands for Read, Evaluate, Print, Loop. The REPL is how you interact with the Python Interpreter.

Comment: @pippo1980 Are you suggesting I should spell out what REPL stands for just in case it's not known? I'm not sure what you mean by the second sentence though. REPLs are *a* way of interacting with the interpreter, but not *the* way.

Comment: Just copied from google  trying to learn python in yhe last couple of years never herad about repl before

Comment: Unless .... The Remote Pilot Licence (RePL) is a licence issued by the Civil Aviation Safety Authority (CASA) that allows Remote Pilots to work under an RPA Operator's Certificate (or ReOC, usually held by an approved business) and to operate medium-sized Excluded RPA (25kg up to 150kg) for agricultural purposes.;-)